# The method 'get' was called on null. Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am trying to make a leaderboard feature for my app and I need to sort a list of firebase users by their score as well as only display the top five users closest to my user's score. I am having an issue whenever I try to sort them where(score, isLessThanOrEqualTo: user score) it will not get the score properly.

Here is the error message.

```
The method 'get' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: get("score")
```

And here is the class where I am sorting the user data.

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  DocumentSnapshot snapshot;


  // Collection reference
  final CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> highscoresCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('highscores');

  Future updateUserData(String name,int score) async {
    return await highscoresCollection.doc(uid).set({
      'score': score,
      'name': name,
    });
  }

  // high scores list from snapshot
  List<HighscoreData> _highscoresListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return HighscoreData(
          name: doc.get('name') ?? '', score: doc.get('score') ?? 0);
    }).toList();
  }


  // Get highscores stream
  Stream<List<HighscoreData>> get highscores{
    return highscoresCollection
              .where(('score'), isLessThanOrEqualTo: snapshot.get('score'))
              .orderBy('score', descending: true,).limit(5)
              .snapshots()
              .map(_highscoresListFromSnapshot);
  }


  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      name: snapshot.get('name'),
      score: snapshot.get('score'),
    );
  }

  // Get user document
  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return highscoresCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help and let me know if you need any more code!

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to the `null` value of given data. You should try `null safety` to avoid this problem. It is better to share the line of your error too. But I think it is related to the one of `snapshot.get('score')` codes. Check the value of `snapshot` and make sure that this value is not null. Also, you can use `snapshot?.get('score')` for null safety. The pattern is like below:

```
variable?.itsParameter
```

---

**Update: Check the null value and assign a default value**
You can check that is `snapshot` value `null`? if yes, assign a default value, or do everything you want as follow:

```
snapshot == null? "Your Default Value" : snapshot.get('score')
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I checked out snapshot, and it is not null. How would I check to see if its null and if it is get the parameter?

Comment: @CameronJohnson Happy to help, see the update section of my answer.